# trying to Disable Strict Mode via SQL

Tags: mysql

Trying to disable Strict Mode true mysql.
I trying with this code.

```
mysql -u root -p -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = ’NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION’;"
```

But i get error code:

```
ERROR 1231 (42000) at line 1: Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of '’NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION’'
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Those quotes around `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` don't look like normal single quotes. Have you tried normal single quotes as well?

Comment: no i havent, i will try that.

Comment: I run this mysql -u root -p -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = "NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";" and test it with this code mysql -u root -p -e "select @@sql_mode".. And it show @@sql_mode NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION..
Reload the mysqld and now it shows: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: `SET GLOBAL` only changes the variable in the current running instance. If MySQL Server restarts, it will read the setting from `/etc/my.cnf` (or wherever your config file is). You should edit your config file as well, so it reads the setting you want when it restarts.

Comment: hello. ok i will try that.